# Dealing with Eastern Standard Time (EST) and Eastern Daylight Savings (EDT) in R

Tags: r, date, time, dst

I have a series of datasets from a water quality continuous monitoring probe with the Date and Time set in Eastern Standard Time (EST) so there is no correction of Daylight Savings Time (EDT). In R, the fields are recognized as factors when importing the data table from an MS access database however when converting using as.POSIXct() dates and times from 02:00 (24 clock) on 2016-03-13 become NAs. This is due to the transition from EST to EDT...therefore technically 2016-03-13 02:00 doesn't exist.

Some created data as an example

`test<-data.frame(Date=rep(as.Date("2016-03-13"),120),Hour=rep(seq(0,23,1),5),Min=rep(seq(0,60,15),24))`

Is there a way to convert the factor or character field to as POSIXct field while retaining the EST timezone designation? Alternatively is there a way to identify and convert the proper date and times into EST and EDT?

I have gone around and around and can't get anything to work. I have attempted to convert to GMT (or UTC) then convert back to EST (tz="America/New_York"). I realize that this is an ongoing issue and people who work with date and time data, especially in R would love to move away from EDT.

Any help is appreciated...I am at my wits end on this one.

Comment: I think I might have found a work around, but I am not 100% sure. When converting datetime from a factor or character to a POSIXct field, using the tz="Etc/GMT-5"  seems to work...but I am still not sure. Any direction or advise is welcomed. Example code below. 


`test<-data.frame(Date=rep(as.Date("2016-03-13"),96),Hour=rep(seq(0,23,1), each=4),Min=rep(seq(0,45,15)))`

`as.POSIXct(paste(test$Date, test$Hour, test$Min), format="%Y-%m-%d %H %M", tz="Etc/GMT-5")`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The trouble with using POSIX `tz = "America/New_York"` is that daylight savings time is accounted for (UTC-4 or UTC-5), even if the underlying timestamps are stored in U.S. Eastern Standard Time (UTC-5).

You should be able to designate your tz as `Etc/GMT+5`. From there, it is easy to convert between EST, Eastern local time, and GMT. Note that in R, time zones west of UTC are denoted with a positive offset (see Time Zone Names documentation in `?timezone`).

Here is some example data (daylight savings took effect at 2:00 AM Eastern Time on 3/16/16):

```
StartTime=as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2016-03-11 0:00:00",format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M",origin="1970-01-01",tz="Etc/GMT+5"))
EndTime=as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2016-03-15 0:00:00",format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M",origin="1970-01-01",tz="Etc/GMT+5"))

Interval=15*60  #15-min
data.EST=as.POSIXct(seq(from = StartTime,to = EndTime, by=Interval),origin="1970-01-01",tz="Etc/GMT+5") #generate date stamps

# convert Eastern Standard Time (in R: GMT+5) to local time (accounts for daylight savings):
data.EastCoast<- format(data.EST, tz="America/New_York")

# convert Eastern Standard Time (in R: GMT+5) to UTC/GMT:
data.UTC<- format(data.EST, tz="GMT")

compare.times<-data.frame(data.EST,data.EastCoast,data.UTC)

compare.times[(198:203),]

               data.EST      data.EastCoast            data.UTC
198 2016-03-13 01:15:00   2016-03-13 01:15:00   2016-03-13 06:15:00
199 2016-03-13 01:30:00   2016-03-13 01:30:00   2016-03-13 06:30:00
200 2016-03-13 01:45:00   2016-03-13 01:45:00   2016-03-13 06:45:00
201 2016-03-13 02:00:00   2016-03-13 03:00:00   2016-03-13 07:00:00
202 2016-03-13 02:15:00   2016-03-13 03:15:00   2016-03-13 07:15:00
203 2016-03-13 02:30:00   2016-03-13 03:30:00   2016-03-13 07:30:00
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

During the conversion to POSIX you need to specify the time zone.  See this example:

```
test<-data.frame(Date=rep(as.Date("2016-03-13"),96),Hour=rep(seq(0,23,1), each=4),Min=rep(seq(0,45,15)))
wrong<-as.POSIXct(paste(test$Date, test$Hour, test$Min), format="%Y-%m-%d %H %M")
ans<-as.POSIXct(paste(test$Date, test$Hour, test$Min), format="%Y-%m-%d %H %M", tz="EST")

compare<-cbind(test, wrong, ans)
```

In the vector "wrong", no timezone was specified thus the NA, but in the second case Eastern Standard was specified and the desired result is given.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have read some conflicting documentation to indicate that "EST" in R refers to "Australian Eastern Standard Time" and not the North American/Canadian "Eastern Standard Time". This makes a big difference as "Australian Eastern Standard Time" is UTC-10 and "Eastern Standard Time" is UTC-5. I am just overall confused regarding timezone notation sometimes as there is so much information out there. Any points would be appreciated.

Comment: See ?timezones and OlsonNames() for the list of possible timezones.  I am on the east coast and running Sys.time() returns - "EDT"

Comment: Thanks, I am also running on the east coast of the US and did Sys.time() and got EDT. Thanks for the input ad guidance.

Comment: For Eastern time in North America, you should use `America/New_York` for the US or `America/Toronto` for Canada.  Don't use abbreviations, as they can be ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into a similar issue using water quality data that does not observe daylight savings time. The workaround I have found useful is to use `America/Jamaica` rather than `America/New_York`. Below are a list of GMT offsets and the `tz` to use.

- -4 = `America/Virgin`
- -5 = `America/Jamaica`
- -6 = `America/Regina`
- -8 = `Pacific/Pitcairn`
- -9 = `Pacific/Gambier`
- -10 = `Pacific/Honolulu`